# Prove that $\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}\ge\frac{3\sqrt3}2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions, tangent-line-method

Given $x,y,z$ are positive number satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Prove that $$\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}+\frac{y}{z^2+x^2}+\frac{z}{x^2+y^2}\ge \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

I need a way use reduction of many fractions to a common denominator

Comment: If you really want the sum under the same denominator you have :
$$\frac{x^5+x^3 y^2+x^3 z^2+x^2 y^3+x^2 y^2 z+x^2 y z^2+x^2 z^3+x y^2 z^2+y^5+y^3z^2+y^2 z^3+z^5}{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)(y^2+z^2)}
$$

Comment: Hint: For $x\in [0,1[$, $\frac{x}{1-x^2}\geq \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}x^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}\geq\frac{3\sqrt3}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}.$$
Since the last inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$ 
and now we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{3-x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{3-x^2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-1)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x(x+2)(x-1)^2}{3-x^2}\geq0$$
Done!

Comment: +1, I was just gonna tag you since you are king of proving inequalities, but then I noticed `1 new answer to this question`, and with no doubt, it's you!

Answer (score 3):

Not hard to see $$x(1-x^2)\le\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}.$$

Then $$\dfrac{x}{1-x^2}\ge \dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}x^2.$$

Then sum over $\{x,y,z\}$ and use $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$