# Inequality Proof $\frac{a}{1-a^2}+\frac{b}{1-b^2}+\frac{c}{1-c^2}\geq \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^+$, and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, show that:
$$ \frac{a}{1-a^2}+\frac{b}{1-b^2}+\frac{c}{1-c^2}\geq \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the problem, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.  Posts which merely state a problem to solve are discouraged on this site.

Comment: i think Cauchy Schwarz will help you!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282219/prove-that-sum-cyc-fracxy2z2-ge-frac3-sqrt32

Answer (score 4):

The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x(1-x^2)}$ takes its minimum at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ on $(0,1)$.

Thus
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{a}{1-a^2}+\frac{b}{1-b^2}+\frac{c}{1-c^2} & = & a^2 f(a) + b^2 f(b) + c^2 f(c)\\
& \ge & (a^2+b^2+c^2)f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right)=  \frac{3\sqrt 3}{2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Nice and simple. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint:  it is enough to show for $x\in (0, 1)$,
$$f(x) = \left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)-\frac{3\sqrt3}2\left(x^2-\frac13 \right) \geqslant 0$$

$$\iff \frac{x(\sqrt3x+2)(3x-\sqrt3)^2}{6(1-x^2)} \geqslant 0$$

Answer (score 1):

By C-S and Schur we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{1-a^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab^2+ac^2}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)}\geq\frac{3(a+b+c)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ab)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{a+b+c}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ab)}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$
Now, let $a^2+b^2+c^2=x(ab+ac+bc).$

Hence, $x\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$4(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq3\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^2+ab)\right)^2$$ or
$$4(x+2)x\geq3(x+1)^2$$ or
$$(x-1)(x+3)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.